# Content editable feature without using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, flask, contenteditable

I'm building a travel planner website, where I want to use the content editable feature from HTML5. I also want to save the changes in my db and retrieve them whenever the user click on the trip webpage. I have found couple of tutorials that touches on that and how it can be done, but all of them mention using php to store these changes to a variable. I don't know anything about php, though this feature is critical in my website. One more thing, I'm using flask web framework, I don't know does that helps my case by any means? So are there any alternative beside php?

Thanks in advance,
Maryam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are loads of alternatives to PHP:

https://www.quora.com/Web-Development-What-are-better-alternatives-for-PHP-and-MySQL

But, pretty much any language you decide on will force you to learn a new programming language.

I, personally, prefer PHP with a jQuery-JavaScript front end.  I really wish there was a better answer, but people always ask this question (including me when I started programming), and there is no real alternative to learning a new server-based language for database and etc. changes.

There is a **very** good reason for this.  If you allowed users to see the code that adds security features, they can edit it (like I do).  And then, **boom**, your site is pwned.

Best regards,

Neil.

Comment: Thanks, One quick question, so Can I substitute the php variable with a python function that could save these changes as a whole webpage and replace the one already stored in db, or it still needs php to do that? I mean I will gladly learn php if I could, but It is a school project, so I'm kinda limited on time and deliverable is next week.

Comment: Some web services support shell_exec which you can use to execute Python scripts on a web server.  I wish you the best.  If you could mark my answer as answer or upvote it, it would help me a lot, any more questions?

Comment: And you can't really keep python functions as variables in php* (You kind of can if you want to write it to a file then execute it).

Comment: I did click on the upvote, thanks A lot !

Comment: Sorry for the excessive questions, just one more thing I'm using SQLALCHEMY does that make a difference or still I need php?

Comment: If you want it to display on a webpage, unfortunately, yes.

Comment: Isn't the python fills the purpose of PHP in my case? Because I'm using python flask to do this website!